# Wordpress Won't parseJSON when I include a special string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, wordpress

I have a system that updates HTML via AJAX when a button is clicked. There is a function that fetches the HTML to be updated (tested and works), a function that sends a JSON encoded array that contains a true or false variable and a string with the updated HTML from the other function and finally the JQuery itself which retrieves the information. The problem is when I try to pass the HTML information through the array there becomes an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

**JQuery Code That Retrieves and Sends Essential Information**

```
    //One of the functions didn't have the data type for testing purposes
        (function ($) {
            $('.arrow-up').click(function () {
            var user_id = $(this).attr('rel');
            var my_data = {
                action: 'arrow_handler', // This is required so WordPress knows which function to use
                move_id: user_id,
                arrow_status: 'up'
            };
            $.post(ajax_url, my_data, function (data) {
               var objprase=$.parseJSON(data); // now obj is a json object
                if (objprase.true == 'true') {
                    alert(objprase.true);
                } else {
                    alert(objprase.true);
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);         
    (function ($) {
            $('.arrow-down').click(function () {
            var user_id = $(this).attr('rel');
            var my_data = {
                action: 'arrow_handler', // This is required so WordPress knows which function to use
                move_id: user_id,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                arrow_status: 'down'
            };
            $.post(ajax_url, my_data, function (data) {
               var objprase=$.parseJSON(data); // now obj is a json object
                if (objprase.true == 'true') {
                    alert("hello");
                } else {
                    alert(objprase.true);
                }
            });
        });
```

**The Function that retrieves the information sent by the Ajax Post and Sends back an encrypted JSON String**

```
// Finds information and sets $truetest to its value            
$htmlreturn = tableReturn(); // tableReturn() gets the new HTML code
$datapasser = array("true" => $truetest, "text" => $htmlreturn);
echo json_encode($datapasser);
die(); // this is required to return a proper result
```

**Post Responce**

```
<table id="blog-table" border="1">
  <tr>    <td align="center">UserName</td>        <td align="center">User ID</td>    <td align="center">Order</td> <td align="center"></td>  <td align="center">Move Up/Down</td>  </tr>
        <tr id="1">    <td>Olesiarpm</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td id="1">1</td>
    <td>
      <button class="del_btn" rel="1">Delete</button>
    </td>
    <td><div class="arrow-down" rel="18"></div> </td>
  <tr id="2">    <td>bluice12</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td id="2">2</td>
    <td>
      <button class="del_btn" rel="2">Delete</button>
    </td>
    <td> <div class="arrow-up" rel="16"></div><br><div class="arrow-down" rel="16"></div>   </td>
  <tr id="3">    <td>fSnNO4Xvlq</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td id="3">3</td>
    <td>
      <button class="del_btn" rel="3">Delete</button>
    </td>
    <td> <div class="arrow-up" rel="35"></div><br><div class="arrow-down" rel="35"></div>   </td>
  <tr id="4">    <td>heklylh5469</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td id="4">4</td>
    <td>
      <button class="del_btn" rel="4">Delete</button>
    </td>
    <td><div class="arrow-up" rel="13"></div>   </td>
      </table>{"true":"1","text":""} // The HTML is not shown in the "text" but instead is behind the brace
```

Comment: `{"true":"1","text":""}` this is the json are you getting or the post response?

Comment: yes. All the HTML before that is supposed to be in the "text"

Comment: when you use utf8_encode it should be something like this `<table id=\"blog-table\" border=\"1\">\n...`

Comment: Should I add backslashes to escape the quotes?

Comment: that's what utf8_econde do \n for new line etc..

Comment: Could It be because tableReturn() isn't returning anything only echoing?

Comment: Did a few tests and its because I was just echoing everything out and wasn't returning values. If that's the case, I'm going to update my code to the current one.

Comment: Because that you never see the json result...

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Can you pass 'json' as the expected data type and don't don't use the jsonParse.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$datapasser=array(
   "true"=>utf8_encode($truetest), 
   "text"=>utf8_encode($htmlreturn)
);
```

I would change this

```
if (objprase.true == 'true') {
    alert(objprase.true);
 } else {
    alert(objprase.true);
 }
```

The if is doing the same thing for true and false

Comment: Still Gives me the error. In the Chrome console when I click on the error it links to                var open=$.parseJSON(data);

Comment: That indicate that the json has wrong format or bad encode...try with firebug and let me know what error are you getting from the console, can you post your json?

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error] (function(e,t){var n,r,i=typeof t,o=e....n),n=d=o=r=null)}),n=s=l=u=r=o=null,t

Comment: post a reduce version of your json to see the characters, if it has any other charset, o symbol...something like that

Comment: the relevant part of your json

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you echo something it won't return a value, it will only print it out. The only way I found out you can do a for loop inside html is to make a string that contains all the html and concatenate to it. Finally, return the string.